# C# Web API to API call

Tags: c#

This is my controller file. From here I am trying to access another library Business logic. In that business logic I have method to access an another API. In that I am facing some error.

```
[ElmahError]
[RoutePrefix("Communication")]
public class CommunicationController : ApiController
{
[Route("GenerateReport")]


        public IHttpActionResult PostGenerateReport(GenerateReportInput objGenerateReportInput)
        {
            GoogleSheetApi _GoogleSheetApi=new GoogleSheetApi();
            try
            {
                string Token = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();
                var apiResponse = new APIResponse();
                string result = _GoogleSheetApi.GenerateReport(objGenerateReportInput, Token);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }

        }
}
```

> Error:  "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "The
>   system cannot find the path specified. ", "ExceptionType":
>   "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException", "StackTrace": "
>   at
>   cube.api.eAxis.Controllers.CommunicationController.PostGenerateReport(GenerateReportInput
>   objGenerateReportInput) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Comment: it is very difficult to debug from the stack trace, because you are doing your error handling wrong. go through all you code, and change "throw e;" to just "throw;"  By adding the "e" you are rethrowing the exception, which breaks up your stack trace. and thus the stack trace of the actual error gets lost.  Also, if your error is in your business logic, why show us the controller code instead of the business logic code ?

Comment: There is an authorize attribute on your action method that is triggering some sort of crypto call, and it's failing because a file is missing. My guess is that there is a private key file, certificate, or some other sensitive data file that your project is configured to use, but the actual file was not checked into source control for security reasons. You might try looking on a known good environment and see if you can find the file there.

Comment: In this code I can run it in local machine. When I deploy the code into server  I get the error. And also here I am trying to access google drive credentials. I have kept my key file in solution folder. When I try to access via server (server also has got the same key file) the server respond that cannot find the file specified.